# Placing of form tag in jsp to pass control to controller to play a video file when clicked in Springmvc

Tags: html, spring-mvc, jsp

I am writing background code for a website where a video file will be played when it will get clicked on the UI page. I have the HTML design page and I converted that to jsp, where should I put the form tag to specify action to pass the control to controller and play the video?

This is the html code and the form tag that I put for the video which i have to play through java coding.

```
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js video-size w-70" controls preload="auto"
     style="" data-setup="{}">
     <form action="play" method="get">
     <source src="https://www.donecode.com/uploads/OnPassive_Cinematic_Trailer_Final.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
     <p class="vjs-no-js"> To view this video please enable JavaScript, and
         consider upgrading to a web browser that <a
             href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/"
             target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a> </p>
             </form>
 </video>
```